# Write a function printWithAge that takes as parameters a file name and an age and prints out the name of each player that is that age

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that has a list of baseball players, their age, and their country code. I'm trying to write a function that would print out the names of all players for a given age:

> ">>> printWithAge('cubsRoster.csv', 35)
>   Tony Barnette
>   Cole Hamels
>   Jon Lester
>
> > > > printWithAge('cubsRoster.csv', 24)
> > > >         Adbert Alzolay
> > > >         Ian Happ
> > > >         Duane Underwood Jr.
> > > >         printWithAge('cubsRoster.csv', 31)
> > > >         Craig Kimbrel
> > > >         printWithAge('cubsRoster.csv', 38)
> > > >         Ben Zobrist"

```
import csv
def printWithAge(filename, age):
    infile = open(cubsRoster.csv, n)
    lines =f.readlines()
    words=line.split(",")
    name=words[0]
    age=words[1]
    csvData = csvReplace.split(',')
    for word in csvData:
        if word==str(n):
            print(word)
```

I get nothing for an output, don't seem to have any errors, but absolutely clueless how to proceed.

Comment: I don't see declaration of the variable `csvData`

Comment: fixed that, still not sure it did anything

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of mistakes in your code:

- `csvData` is not declared
- You're taking `filename` as an input parameter but hardcoding the
  filename inside your function as `infile = open(cubsRoster.csv, n)`
- `n` is also not defined
- `lines =f.readlines(); words=line.split(",")` where you don't loop over the lines but in the next line you try to access `line`

Please follow this piece of code

```py
def printWithAge(filename, n_age):
    infile = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        name, age = line.split(",")
        if int(age) == int(n_age):
            print(f"Name: {name}, Age: {age}")

printWithAge('cubsRoster.csv', 24)
```

Comment: there is one more column `country code` in csv, & its `infile.readlines()`

Comment: Change to this line `name, age, country = line.split(",")`